# Existence of a holomorphic function with the desired property

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $D=\{z\in \mathbb C:|z|<1\}$.
Then does there exist

1.a holomorphic function $f:D\to \overline D$ with  $f(0)=0$ and $|f(\frac{1}{3})|=\frac{1}{4}$ ?

2.a holomorphic function $f:D\to \overline D$ with  $f(0)=0$ and $f(\frac{1}{3})=\frac{1}{2}$ ?

How to approach these?I am new to complex analysis.So please do provide some hints or the theorems that can help me here?

Comment: $\frac{3}{4}·\frac{1}{3} = \frac{1}{4}$ and $\lvert\frac{3}{4}\rvert < 1$. Otherwise, use the open mapping theorem and the Schwarz lemma.

Comment: why $\overline{D}$? I believe by the [Open Mapping Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_mapping_theorem_%28complex_analysis%29), the image should be at least an open subset of $\overline{D}$. I'm not confident that it would necessarily be the open disk, but if so, [Schwarz Lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_lemma) should be of some assistance. Hope that helps.

Comment: @Blake $f(D) ⊂ (\overline D)° = D$.

Answer (score 0):

For 1,  use $\frac{3}{4}·\frac{1}{3} = \frac{1}{4}$ and $\lvert\frac{3}{4}\rvert < 1$.

For 2, use the [open mapping theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_mapping_theorem_(complex_analysis)) and the [Schwarz lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_lemma).

Comment: i did not get 1 any more hints

Comment: @learnmore Linear maps are holomorphic, what are the linear maps $ℂ → ℂ$? Which one of these restrict to $D → D$?